# LINQ GroupBy or something else for a single loop?

Tags: c#, linq

This object (greatly simplified) is basically this:

```
public class Site
{
   public string SiteId { get; set; }//unique
   public string SiteName { get; set; }
   public string NetworkId { get; set; } //unique
   public string NetworkName { get; set; }

}
```

I would like the end result to be:

```
Network 1
  Site 1
  Site 2
Network 2
  Site 1
  Site 2
  Site 3
```

Edit for clarity:
<strike>I could just outer loop all the networks and then inner loop all the sites that belong to that network.</strike>

I'm using **2 loops**. One outer one for the unique NetworkId and one inner one for the unique SiteId.

I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish the same result with a **single loop**. I realize that a GroupBy return IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> but I'm not sure how to use that for my preferred result.

Edit adding details:

Can I accomplish the end result in a single foreach loop if I use a GroupBy?

How would I accomplish the end result output if I used a GroupBy on the NetworkId?

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Currently I'm just using the 2 loop solution. I'm working on a single loop solution. It seems that GroupBy is the part of the answer, but I haven't figured out how to work with the resulting IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> to get the result.

Comment: `using the 2 loop solution`, nothing in your post says anything about `2 loops`? Where's the code for this? It would help so we can point you in the right direction, only assumptions and or opinions can be made at most here. How are you creating these objects?

Comment: I mention it here. "I could just outer loop all the networks and then inner loop all the sites that belong to that network."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `GroupBy` is your friend. What should be the end result? Maybe a `Dictionary<(string, string), List<Site>>` where the key is the combination of `NetworkId` and `NetworkName`(in case the name is not unique)?

```
Dictionary<(string Id, string Name), List<Site>> networkSites = allSites
    .GroupBy(s => (s.NetworkId, s.NetworkName))
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.OrderBy(s => s.SiteId).ToList());
```

Output:

```
foreach(var kv in networkSites)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key.Name} {kv.Key.Id}");
    foreach(var site in kv.Value)
        Console.WriteLine($"{site.SiteName} {site.SiteId}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq

```
var result = sites.GroupBy(x => x.NetworkName).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(x=>x.SiteId).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `GroupBy` followed by `ToDictionary`, you could create a lookup:

```
var lookup = sites.ToLookup(x => x.NetworkId, x => x.SiteId);
```

The `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` is an immutable structure that allows an `IEnumerable<TValue>` to be retrieved using an indexer:

```
var sitesForNetwork1 = lookup[1];
```